# Mozilla Thunderbird Addon - Create Task

Tags: firefox-addon, google-calendar-api, mozilla, add-on, thunderbird-addon

I am beginner to Mozilla Addons Development. I need some help for developing a functionality ie. Assign task Manager it is like Lightning Addon.

When I would click on a button a popup should come asking for subject, start date, due date, assignTo(email ID). When we click on save and send, it should send an RSVP(invitation mail). If user accepts the invitation It should be updated in sqlite database. How to do this. Anyone having some code or suggestion. I think we need to use Google Calenders in this addon but I am not getting how to use it in addon development to create task and send invitation.

Also what is the use of .ics file, if anyone know then please let me know.

Thanks. I would be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

heres an example of a task i made recently:

```
var dJsm = Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Downloads.jsm").Downloads;
var tJsm = Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm").Task;
var fuJsm = Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm").FileUtils;

var view = {
    onDownloadChanged: function(download) {
        cDump(download, 'Changed');
        if (download.succeeded) {
            var file = fuJsm.File(this.target.path));
            cDump(file,'file);
        }
    }
  };
tJsm.spawn(function () {

  let list = yield dJsm.getList(Downloads.ALL);
    list.addView(view);
 //list.removeView(view);

}).then(null, Components.utils.reportError);

                    function cDump(obj,title) {
                        var tstr = '';
                        var bstr = '';
                        var fstr = '';
                        for (var b in obj) {
                            try {
                                bstr += b + '=' + obj[b] + '\n';
                            } catch (e) {
                                fstr = b + '=' + e + '\n';
                            }
                        }
                        tstr += '<b>BSTR::</b>\n' + bstr;
                        tstr += '\n<b>FSTR::</b>\n' + fstr;
                        var cWin = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
                        var onloadFunc = function () {
                            cWin.gBrowser.selectedTab = cWin.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[cWin.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes.length - 1];
                            newTabBrowser.removeEventListener('load', onloadFunc, true);
                            if (title) { newTabBrowser.contentDocument.title = title; }
                            newTabBrowser.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = tstr.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')
                        };
                        var newTabBrowser = cWin.gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(cWin.gBrowser.addTab('about:blank'));
                        newTabBrowser.addEventListener('load', onloadFunc, true);
                    }
```